# No artifacts found that match the file pattern "**/target/*.apk"

Tags: android, maven, jenkins

I got this output from Jenkins console while trying to compile an android project: 
just notice that I didn't make any change on the main Class
this is the jenkins console:

```
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 10.701s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu May 29 17:56:45 CEST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 24M/491M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/opt/jenkins/workspace/Android-Project-App/trunk/pom.xml to com.proj.android.project.mobile/project-android/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/project-android-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/opt/jenkins/workspace/Android-Project-App/trunk/assets/build/project-android.apk to com.proj.android.project.mobile/project-android/0.0.1-20140529.155643-5/project-android-0.0.1-20140529.155643-5.apk
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/opt/jenkins/workspace/Android-Project-App/trunk/assets/build/project-android.jar to com.proj.android.project.mobile/project-android/0.0.1-20140529.155643-5/project-android-0.0.1-20140529.155643-5.jar
channel stopped
Archiving artifacts
ERROR: No artifacts found that match the file pattern "**/target/*.apk". Configuration error?
ERROR: ‘**/target/*.apk’ doesn’t match anything: ‘**’ exists but not ‘**/target/*.apk’
Build step 'Archive the artifacts' changed build result to FAILURE
IRC notifier plugin: Sending notification to: #jenkins
Finished: FAILURE
```

and this is my pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.proj</groupId>
        <artifactId>android</artifactId>
        <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.proj.android.project.mobile</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-android</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <name>project Android Application</name>
    <description>project mobile application for android client</description>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <issueManagement>
        <system>jira</system>
        <url>http://www/jira/browse/${jira.project.key}</url>
    </issueManagement>
    <scm>
        <connection>scm:svn:http://svn/android/project-mobile-app/trunk/</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://svn/android/project-mobile-app/trunk/</developerConnection>
        <url>http://svn/web/wsvn/android/project-mobile-app/</url>
    </scm>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- Android dependencies -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>android</groupId>
                <artifactId>android</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
                <version>4.0.3_r2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>android</groupId>
                <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
                <version>r6</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
                <version>${junit.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>bouncycastle</groupId>
                <artifactId>bcprov-jdk14</artifactId>
                <version>138</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- <dependency> -->
            <!-- <groupId>com.proj.android.sample</groupId> -->
            <!-- <artifactId>pdf-viewer-ng</artifactId> -->
            <!-- <type>apklib</type> -->
            <!-- <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version> -->
            <!-- </dependency> -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.proj.project.client</groupId>
                <artifactId>project-client</artifactId>
                <version>${project-client.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <sourceDirectory>build</sourceDirectory>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/assets/build</directory>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <extractDuplicates>true</extractDuplicates>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <android.version>4.0.3_r2</android.version>
        <android.sdk>15</android.sdk>
        <android.emulator.avd>AVD_15_4_0_3</android.emulator.avd>
        <jira.project.key>UNIAPPAND-1</jira.project.key>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <com.proj.project.client>1.0-SNAPSHOT</com.proj.project.client>
    </properties>
</project>
```

I think my problem come from target directory because jenkins mentioned that.
I had 3 directories at jenkins: assets ,res et src
Should I add more then these three folders?  for example libs or target ??

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The **Archive Artifacts** post-build step does not care about your POM. All it does is look for files in your workspace folder, i.e `$WORKSPACE` (also accessible through `http://[jenkins-url]/job/[job-name]/ws` ) and archives those within Jenkin's build history.

The files that you are trying to archive must exist in the `$WORKSPACE`. From your configuration, you are trying to archive `**/target/*.apk` which means *"under any path, folder `target` with any file and extension `.apk`"*. It can't find that, since your workspace doesn't have folder `target` anywhere, hence the `ERROR: ‘**/target/*.apk’ doesn’t match anything: ‘**’ exists but not ‘**/target/*.apk’`

In your POM file, you have the following line:
`<directory>${project.basedir}/assets/build</directory>`
This is what identifies where your built files end up. It is `[base-dir-of-pom]/assets/build`, not `target`.

Also, form your console log:
`[JENKINS] Archiving /var/opt/jenkins/workspace/Android-Project-App/trunk/assets/build/project-android.apk`
Which further proves that your `.apk` artifact is in fact located under `trunk/assets/build`

For your **Archive Artifacts** file pattern, you need to use:
`**/assets/build/*.apk`

And as a matter of fact, you could use just:
`**/build/*.apk` or even
`**/*.apk`

But the question is: do you really want to be archiving the artifacts on Jenkins (which takes space) when you are already archiving the artifacts with Maven?

Comment: you mean the error is located here:

 `<finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
  <sourceDirectory>build</sourceDirectory>
  <directory>${project.basedir}/assets/build</directory>`

Comment: It's not an "error". In your POM, you specify that the built file should go to `${project.basedir}/assets/build` folder but in Jenkins's archive configuration, you are looking for file under `target` folder. There is nothing wrong with either location, **but they have to match**. It is simpler/better to modify the Jenkins's archive configuration than to change the POM. Did you try my suggestion of `**/assets/build/*.apk`?

Comment: thanks Slav I solved it by change it to target because jenkins's configured to build all to /target

Comment: I have the same problem but instead of Maven i'm using Gradle, and still Jenkins can't find my artifacsts.
I've tried to give permisions and still nothing.
PS. When open workspace dir from Jenkins UI, there is no build folder, but when open it from command line there is. 
I'dont know what is happening.

I've tried with pattern that are the answer and with full path for the .apk file and still Jenkins  can't find it.

Comment: @Balflear on the file system (from command line as you say), each job has a `builds` and `workspace` folders. The `workspace` folder is what Jenkins uses for each **current** execution. The `builds` folder is where **past** builds are kept. Inside the builds folder, there are subfolders for each past build, and inside that, there is an `archive` folder (if configured). The Jenkins UI "workspace" link only shows the `workspace` folder. The `builds` folder is what makes up the "build history" section of the job.

Comment: @SLAV The problem was that i was used slave node, and jenkins can't see the files created by the slave node(Don't know why). After i start using the master node everything is fine now...

Comment: @Balflear glad you got it working. There is also a plugin that lets you copy files to/from slave nodes https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+To+Slave+Plugin

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to archive release.apk, and I ran into the same trouble as you. Jenkins prompts me should do like: app/build/outputs/apk/yourAppName/release/*.apk, and it fixed my problem.

[image: Jenkins job config snapshort]