# Jenkins Pipeline with androidApkUpload not finding APKs

Tags: android, jenkins

I have an existing Freestyle Jenkins job that I want to run through Pipeline. After the job is completed, I want to use `androidApkUpload` to upload APKs to Google Play Store. The problem is that the `androidApkUpload` step can't find my APKs. I think this is happening because my pipeline job is under a different workspace folder, however I'm not sure. I've tried different paths in `apkFilesPattern` but nothing seems to be working. I'm getting an error:

`No APK files matching the pattern: '../android-job/app/build/outputs/apk/*.apk`

or if I try anything else like for example an absolute file path:

`No APK files matching the pattern: '/jenkins/workspace/android-job/app/build/outputs/apk/*.apk`

I've tried quite a few different combinations of the file pattern and nothing really worked, including the example `**/*.apk`

An example of my simple pipeline:

```
//build 'android-app'
node('android') {
step([$class: 'ApkPublisher', apkFilesPattern: '**/*.apk', googleCredentialsId: 'google-play-upload', recentChangeList: [[language: 'en-GB', text: 'Test']], trackName: 'beta'])
}
```

Build takes a long time so I've uncommented it for now, but the APKs are there, in that job's workspace folder.

Has anyone tried a similar setup?

Comment: It looks as well.If the operating system is Windows, can you try to use backslash once?

Comment: It's Linux. Found a workaround anyway by migrating my freestyle build into the pipeline

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue generating the apks with gulp. Athought the apk was in the exact path I put, it did not work and neither the general example (maybe because there are several apks under $WORKSPACE? Who knows)- Following this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23938310/no-artifacts-found-that-match-the-file-pattern-target-apk) I found the solution, in my case I finally put

`apkFilesPattern: '**/apk/android-release.apk'`

but I guesss **/build/*.apk should also work.